# Rails How to add a input box so that when the user clicks the button the parameters are passed to the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to include a text box where the user can enter a check number and that check number gets included in the params when the user clicks the button. I am a beginner; here's the code:

```
<% if @mailer.present? %>

    <% @mailer.each do |mailer| %>
  <p>
    <%= mailer.lead.full_name %> </br>
    <%= mailer.lead.address%> 
    <%= mailer.lead.address2%> </br>
    <%= mailer.lead.city%>
    <%= mailer.lead.state%>
    <%= mailer.lead.zip_code%>
    <%= link_to "Edit Contact", edit_lead_path(mailer.lead.id) %>
  </p>  

<p>
 <strong>Control Number:</strong>
  <%= mailer.id %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Mail date:</strong>
  <%= mailer.mail_date %>
</p>


<p>
  <strong>Magazine:</strong>
  <%= mailer.magazine %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Umc:</strong>
  <%= mailer.umc_id %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Years:</strong>
  <%= mailer.years %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Full price:</strong>
  <%= mailer.full_price %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Partial price:</strong>
  <%= mailer.partial_price %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Agent:</strong>
  <%= mailer.agent_id %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>No thanks:</strong>
  <%= mailer.no_thanks %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Purchased:</strong>
  <%= mailer.purchased %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Lead:</strong>
  <%= mailer.lead_id %>
</p>

<%= button_to 'Process Payment', process_payment_path(:id => mailer.id, :type => 'CK', :pmt => mailer.full_price) %> 

Input box here! The user can enter a check number into the input box. Then when they click on the button "Process Payment" it includes the input in the button click above.

<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks guys

Comment: I know its tempting to just jump into programming, though you need to read some starting tutorials, all this should be covered better the us trying to understand code that isnt included.. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html.

Comment: to help get you on the right track, though you didnt include your controller code, i would suggest looking at your `mailer_controller` and find the `mailer_params` method and include `check_number` as a permitted params.  Then just add a form to your view and pass it normally.

Comment: Ricky, I will read those manuals. I have referred to them for help, but you are right I need to read them. I have taken the Lynda rails course, the Hartl video instructions and built that app alongside Chris. Any other recommendation (books, video's etc) would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Processing a payment in a GET request is a really bad idea since your app will process the the payment again if the user clicks the back button!**

Instead you should use a POST request. The simplest way to send a post request is with a form:

```
<form action="/payments" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Process payment"/>
</form>
```

**Also never send the amount for a payment via a parameter unless you want your users to determine what they think your products or services are worth!** Any malicious user with half a brain cell can do `/proccess_payment?pmt=0`.

Instead you persist an object *to be payed* in the database and then send the id to the controller which processes the payment.

**This is a basic example of how you would set it up in rails:**

```
# config/routes
resources :mailers, shallow: true
  resources :payments
end
```

---

```
# app/models/payment.rb
model Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  METHODS = %w( CK )   
  belongs_to :mailer
  validates_inclusion_of :type, in: METHODS
end

# app/models/mailer.rb
model Mailer < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  has_many :payments
end
```

---

```
# app/controllers/payments_controller.rb
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_mailer, only: [:create, :index]

  # POST /mailers/:mailer_id/payments
  def create
    @payment = @mailer.payments.new(payment_params)
    @amount = @payment.mailer.full_price # is not user input!
    # @todo actually process the payment. 
    # usually this involves redirecting to payment portal.
  end

  def payment_params
    params.require(:payment).allow(:type, :amount)
  end
end
```

---

Set up a new Payment in your MailerController which is used for the form:

```
def show 
  # ...
  @payment = @mailer.payment.new 
end
```

create a form in the view:

```
...
<p>
  <strong>Lead:</strong>
  <%= mailer.lead_id %>
</p>

<%= form_for(@mailer, @payment) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_input :type, value: 'CK' %>
  <%= f.number_field :pmt, in: 12..24 %>
  <%= f.submit 'Process Payment' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Max, thank you for the response. Couple of things. Would you ever consider being my rails mentor, I would be willing to pay you. Now to the code, with the form, it is meant for our customer service reps to use to process incoming orders, not the general public. Even still I have a lot to learn and I'm going to study the code and figure out what you are accomplishing, and edit mine accordingly. As I mentioned, I am a beginner and, like you rails makes me happy. Again if you would consider being a paid mentor please let me know.

Comment: The reason for the custom payment amount is that sometimes a customer sends us a check for $10 and we are expecting a check for either $12(partial payment) or $24(full payment). So a customer service rep needs to enter the custom amount into the payments table. Thanks!

Comment: I have a little too much going on currently to take a up tutoring but thanks for asking. I edited the answer which lets the user set the amount via the form (which is OK when in this case as it's a trusted source). I also changed the field naming to mirror the original question.

Comment: Thanks Max! I will get it updated and give a thumbs up. I really appreciate the effort and help.